# Will having a typo in domain name affect google SEO rankings?

Tags: seo, google, domains

Will having a typo(misspelling) in domain name affect google SEO rankings?

for example - using shoppin instead of shopping in between domain name.

example shoppinglot.com vs shoppinlot.com

Comment: For example...? A realistic example would be best.

Comment: Please add some more information to clarify this (i.e., where is the typo, how significant is it, etc...).

Comment: for example - using shoppin instead of shopping in between domain name...

Comment: What does "in between domain name" mean? Please provide an actual example, and where it would appear (i.e., in the text, the actual URL visitors would use, etc...).

Comment: example shoppinglot.com    vs    shoppinlot.com